# formGroup falla al intentar validad un formulario

Tags: angular, angular8

```
<form [formGroup]="altaForm" (ngSubmit)="onAltaCampo()">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-send">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

En el component tengo la función:

```
onAltaCampo(){console.log('Funciona!!!');}
```

Pero me da un error:

> compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("][formGroup]="altaForm" (ngSubmit)="onAltaCampo()">

Comment: tienes definido el FormGroup en el component.ts? y tienes importado el FormsModule en el module.ts? Podrias mostrar el component.ts donde definis el formulario?. Necesitamos ver mas codigo para poder ayudarte

Comment: Si lo tengo. @EmilianoTorres   altaForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(  ) {
    // console.log(location);
    console.log('En gestión campos component!!!');
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.altaForm = new FormGroup({
      nombreCampo: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      tipoCampo: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      desdeHastaCampo: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      obligatorioCampo: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    });
   }

Comment: Prueba a importar en el modulo ReactiveFormsModule,de import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

Comment: Lo tengo en aap.modules.ts:  imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rnhugb , no encuentro ningun error, si pudieras poner mas codigo se agracederia

Comment: @danit esa parte ya la tengo solucionada, gracias. ahora tengo otro error... <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="SI" data-off="NO" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-width="50" data-height="1" data-size="mini" formControlName="desdeHastaCampo"> Como hago para coger el valor seleccionado?. Me llega vacío al component.

Comment: en el metodo onAltaCampo, puedes hacer this.altaForm.get('desdeHastaCampo').value para obtener el valor del campo

Comment: Me llega vacío. Los demás input's que tengo que no tienen eso de data-togle si que llegan perfectamente excepto este.

Comment: los data son solos atributos personalizados para dar informacion, el atributo que te interesa es value , que solo puede ser true o false ya que es un checkbox